# How to show that, for a linear code C, that the covering radius of the code is the same as the weight of the coset of largest weight.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, coding-theory

I am in an independent study using the text by Huffman and Pless titled *Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes*. **I am trying to prove that the covering radius $\rho(C)$ for a linear code is the same as the weight of the coset with largest weight.** The proof strategy seems to be pretty standard, i.e. we show that each quantity is less than or equal to the other.

So far, by definition, the *covering radius* is given by

$\rho(\mathcal C)$ = $\underset{x\in \mathbb F_q^n}{max}$ $\underset{c\in \mathcal C}{min}$ $d(x,c)$.

Additionally, the *weight of a coset* is the smallest weight of a vector in the coset, where any vector of this smallest weight is called a *coset leader*. Two vectors **x** and **y** belong to the same coset if and only if **y**-**x** $\in \mathcal C$.

I know this isn't much, but I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any hints to point me in the right direction are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

"Hint":

Can you show that (here $w\in C$) if
$$
d(x,w)=\min_{c\in C}d(x,c),
$$
then $w-x$ is a leader of the coset $-x+C$?

And conversely :-)

Comment: Okay, so our equation basically just means that $w$ is a codeword that is minimally distant from $x$. And, for the forward direction, what we want to show is that $w$ has the smallest weight in the coset $-x + C$. I am having trouble picturing $-x + C$. I am just not quite sure how we can even show that $w$ is in the coset $-x+C$. We know $w$ would lie in the coset $-x+C$ provided $w-(-x) = w+x \in C$, or alternatively, that $syn(-x) = syn(w)$. This is about all I have come up with from your hint thus far. Still pondering the converse.

Comment: Nevermind, I guess it is clear to me that $w+x \in C$, and so $w \in -x+C$. Now I just need to show it's the smallest weight element, which I am still mulling over. I appreciate this very much and will continue to mull it over.

Comment: Best of luck @ChaoticGood :-)

Comment: @ChaoticGood There was a potentially very confusing typo in the answer. $w-x$ is the coset leader. Sorry about that.